# Was the apparition Shion saw in his flashbacks Izanagi?

Tags: darker-than-black

In flashbacks of when a star fell while Shion and his father was camping, in the reflection of his eye there's an apparition like Yin's possessed specter, was this Izanagi or was Shion born as Izanagi?

EDIT: From an answer, it's clear the apparition was not Izanagi. However, I did type the description wrong, as I'm asking about the apparition Shion saw after the star struck him and his father.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to awakening, Izanagi was a gold humanoid specter (we see this at the end of the OVA when Yin talks to izanagi). So as izanagi was not yet awakened, if Shion saw a gold specter, he was seeing Izanagi. But, if he saw himself, he was seeing Shion.

I could not find this scene in the anime, but Izanagi only awakens at the end of the series, so up until then Izanagi would be a gold specter.

EDIT: The scene is at 09:20 in episode 11. That is not Shion or Izanagi; rather, it is Yin's evolved specter. I do not know the relevance of that scene, but Yin may have been Kirsi at that time and not yet a doll, so Shion may have been seeing the future.

Comment: the scene i'm talking about is when Suou learns that she's not real and we see for the first time the real memory of the campfire where Shion and his father see the meteor shower and a star falls on them, i think my description is wrong as i ask at the end about Izanagi but i'm actually asking about what the apparition Shion saw after the star hit them

Comment: I found the scene, it is yins evloved specter.